# How do I set a previous paste buffer in tmux back to the active buffer?

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to get a previous `tmux` paste buffer back to the active buffer (the one that's pasted when pressing <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>)?

E.g. I have

```
(0) buffer2: 21:56: bar
(1) buffer1: 21:55: foo
```

in my paste buffers (seen when I press <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>). Pressing <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> will paste `bar`. How do I get it back so pressing <kbd>Prefix</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> pastes `foo` without deleting all the ones above it?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I have found the trick to do what I want is to run tmux command:

```
choose-buffer -Z "run \"tmux saveb -b %% - | tmux loadb -\""
```

This copies the chosen buffer into the current paste buffer.